# How to remove the mapbox marker

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have a function called draw() . I pass in the array value inside draw() to plot my desired marker on the map and its working well!!

```
function  draw(j){
      
    //for (let j =0; j< countvalue[0]; j++){
      array[j].features.forEach(function (marker) {
        // create a HTML element for each feature
        var el = document.createElement('div');
        el.className = 'marker';

var el = document.createElement('div');
el.className = 'marker';


el.style.backgroundImage =
'url(https:gin/images/pin.png)';
el.style.width = marker.properties.iconSize[0] + 'px';
el.style.height = marker.properties.iconSize[1] + 'px';
el.style.backgroundSize = '100%';
        // make a marker for each feature and add it to the map
    
        new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
          .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
          .setPopup(
            new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: 25 }) // add popups
              .setHTML('</h3><p>' + marker.properties.description + '</p>' )
          )
          .addTo(map);
});

}
```

My Question:

How will i call the draw() function to remove the marker? Pardon me if this is not possible. Thanks a lot for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a list of markers that are being added to the map and pass a value to clear all existing markers when required.

```js
let markersList = []

function  draw(j, clearAll){
      
     if(clearAll){
       if(markersList){
         for (var i = markersList.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
           markersList[i].remove();
        }
      }
     }
    //for (let j =0; j< countvalue[0]; j++){
      array[j].features.forEach(function (marker) {
        // create a HTML element for each feature
        var el = document.createElement('div');
        el.className = 'marker';

var el = document.createElement('div');
el.className = 'marker';


el.style.backgroundImage =
'url(https:gin/images/pin.png)';
el.style.width = marker.properties.iconSize[0] + 'px';
el.style.height = marker.properties.iconSize[1] + 'px';
el.style.backgroundSize = '100%';
        // make a marker for each feature and add it to the map
    
        const newMarker = new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
          .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
          .setPopup(
            new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: 25 }) // add popups
              .setHTML('</h3><p>' + marker.properties.description + '</p>' )
          )
          .addTo(map);

        markersList.push(newMarker);
});

}
```

Comment: but what can i pass in my function draw() to do that? Thank you !!

Comment: Do you only want to show one marker at any point or multiple markers?

Comment: i show multiple markers. If i pass in draw(value2) another marker also comes up. Now all my markers are coming but i need to find a way to remove them when the draw function is called. Thanks !!!

Comment: Updated the answer based on requirement, let me know if this helps

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. So now when i want to draw the marker i call draw(value, ?)  . For removing i call draw(value, clearAll) ? Thanks a lot man....

Comment: For clearing the markers draw(j, true), if you want to add without clearing existing markers draw(j, false)

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. but unfortunately its not working.  :(

Comment: Can you share a codesandbox link  so I can take a look and provide a solution